# Is the following code returning a reference to a stack object or is it valid?

Tags: c++, object, reference, return, stack

I have this code which calls a function in the current process from a DLL that returns the value by reference. One person I talk to says it is correct and another states that it is returning a reference to a stack object and that it is undefined behaviour. I am unsure which person is more factual as I don't have as much experience as either of them.

```
// Function call inside of the current process at a specific address. 
// Returns a matrix from the given meshcomponent and an id
FMatrix* GetMatrix(MeshComponent* mesh, FMatrix* result, int id) {
    return reinterpret_cast<FMatrix*(__fastcall*)(MeshComponent*, FMatrix*, int)>(address)(mesh, result, id);
}

// Gets the wanted 3D Vector out of the Matrix
void GetLocation(MeshComponent* mesh, FVector* result, int id) {
    FMatrix matrix;
    GetMatrix(mesh, &matrix, id);  <-- // When the function ends, is it possible for other stack operations to overwrite the matrix? Or is this valid?
    *result = static_cast<FVector>(matrix.WPlane);
}

// Usage, running from a DLL inside the process:
...
FVector location;
GetLocation(mesh, &location, id);
...
```

The code as it is does work, but if it is truly returning a reference to a stack object, I know that could break at any point and I will change it accordingly.

Comment: What is `FVector` is it a pointer?

Comment: I don't see any code returning a reference to a stack object. By invoking `GetMatrix` you are passing a pointer to a stack object as a parameter.

Comment: FVector is just a struct of a 3D Vector containing {x, y, z}.

Comment: Meta-answer: let the person who claims that a reference to a stack object is returned point out both the stack object and the alleged reference to it. It's way harder to prove the absence of something, and the burden of proof should be on the person who is making the easily verifiable claim.

Comment: Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment

> FVector is just a struct of a 3D Vector containing {x, y, z}

this line **copies**  data to a location pointed by `result`

```
*result = static_cast<FVector>(matrix.WPlane);
```

There is no returning by reference. Example for this would be

```
int& foo() {
    static int i;
    return i;
}
```